# GRAPH API 2.8 friends' location

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I am trying to develop a Facebook app, and the internet has been tossing me around with mixed questions and answers about the ability to access the user's friends' location or hometown. after API 2.0, I understand that my app will only access the information of the friends who have used the app themselves. But after playing with Graph API explorer I got very limited info about the friends. 
I just need one simple answer so I can stop looking and move on. Is there a way for my app to get the friends' location if they have used the app before? or that's not possible.

Comment: You can only get location from people that granted user_location to the app

Comment: No, you can just get friend name and fb id;

Comment: You can not get friend name and fb id either. Only form users that are using the app

Comment: so does that mean only get the location of previous users who have granted user_location to the app?

Comment: Of course it means that.